# ConstraintLayout width wrap_content or 0dp

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ededed"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.guna.testapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fdfdfd"
        android:text="Hello world"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvContent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvHeader" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This gives me following output

[image]

No problem with this. But if `tvHeader` has only text `Hello`,

[image]

Look, header `width` changed to smaller one and aligned center.

Okay, If I changed the `layout_width` of `tvHeader` to `0dp` look out the outputs.

[image]

[image]

So, my question is, i want my layout should expand horizontally as much as possible, how can I achieve that? It's not necessary to use `ConstraintLayout`, even `LinearLayout` is enough for me.

Comment: You are missing the `end` constraint on the second `TextView`. Add that and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare No Friend, it doesn't work.

Comment: why not use tv header width, say 200dp? I might not sure about the requirement

Comment: I can't fix the width, I need it to be expanded as much as required. If content is bigger I need bigger layout.

Comment: Is the problem that when you have the just "Hello" in the fist layout you do not want the text to be centered? If so have you tried removing the constraintEnd from the first text view?

Answer (score 0):

Make the constraint 'match parent' in both width and height.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ededed">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fdfdfd"
        android:text="Hello world"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvHeader"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvHeader" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Well, try this.

Comment: parent layout should not have match parent.

Comment: Do you mean in your code? As there is no general rule such that. That's y asking?

Comment: No, In your code `ConstraintLayout` width and height is match_parent, I want it to be wrap_content.

Comment: Ok make it wrap content. And try my remaining code?

Comment: I want the output like my first screenshot in any situation. Is that possible?

Comment: You have wrapped the contents of the entire layout. Then when we specify the first TextView as match_parent, and the second TextView's start constraint to the first TextView' start. You can achieve such output. Try my code and tell by changing the parent layout's width and height to mathc parent

Comment: For me it doesn't work, Can you change the tvHeader's text as Hello, and confirm me whether this works for you.

Comment: If we set match_parent to parent layout, then that background color will added to whole width right?

Comment: Well it works for me. From my code, just change the parent layout's width and height to wrap_content. Everything else should work.

Comment: And as you asked abt the color, I have edited my answer so that you can achieve what you want by keeping the parent layout's width match_parent. Try that out. If working, pls accept the answer.

Comment: It fills #ededed with whole width.

Comment: dont give that color in parent. Just add that in the textview you want, as you dont want it spread across the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `android:maxlines="1"` attribute of in your textView so that the text gets limited to only one line doing this will not let the textview expand vertically. Also wrap the textviews in a vertical linearlayout

I have also optimized your layout, as it is ideal to have 16dp of margin from the screen and a bit of margin in between sibling views. And also rearranged the constraints. Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="#ededed"
    android:padding="1dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fdfdfd"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Hello world"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Hello world" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: For long text, this works, if header has only `hello`, it doesn't fill.

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: I have updated the answer please check if it fulfills your requirements

Comment: Some text missing in longer text.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just wrap the both textViews in a vertical linearLayout instead of the constraintLayout LIKE SO:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ededed"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       tools:context="com.guna.testapplication.MainActivity">
    
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fdfdfd"
            android:text="Hello world dxifjzsiodjivchdivhxkddsiff"/>
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello world"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**AND** you can also use the `android:maxlines="1"` attribute to limit the contents of the textView to one line.

Comment: For shorter text tvHeader becomes smaller.

Comment: Yea for that case simply set the header textView width to match parent!!

Comment: What about if I have two ViewGroups instead of TextView. I'm looking something elegant and simple solution. It should work whatever it is. It should fill with parent's width, but parent should have wrap_content.